# Load testing server log-in

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I'm a developer with no test-experience.

I am currently investigating how to load test a server that handles log-ins from an mobile app. The users usually logs in at the beginning of their work-shift. Therefor there will be a heavy load during the morning when everyone wants to log-in. We have had some issues with the server crashing with high loads and I want to replicate this behavior to analyze it.

I got the source-code to a previously developed application that tests logging in, where I am able to add a list of users and and let them log-in x amount of times. It uses a backgroundWorker, but from what I can gather this will still only use one thread and the requests will be sent synchronously and thus not be an accurate representation of the actual load in production?

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (IClient client in clientList)
    {
        RunTest(client);
    }     
}
```

How can I modify this to better reflect the actual usage? Or is there an easier way to test the load?

I have looked into using tasks and TPL. But I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around it.

If I instead do:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (IClient client in clientList)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RunTest(client));  
    }     
}
```

Will this "automatically" start a new thread and manage it?

Comment: Have a look at [Jmeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/)

Comment: Testing load from a single node to a server is difficult because it's not a real work scenario, and there is likely to be more factors than just login amounts that come into play. If it is a HTTP server you are connecting to, you could use a tool like [ab](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) to perform a benchmark. It might also be worth opening up the application to a subset of beta users to get them to try it out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Though it is not a http-server and I beta-testing isn't really an option.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is wrong `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` is launching a background thread-pool thread and so is the `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ... });` call. There is no point in doing this what-so-ever as far as I can see.

I would do the testing serially, why do you need to multi-thread it? So something like:

```
private void RunLoadTests()
{
    foreach (IClient client in clientList)
        RunIsolatedTest(client));    
}
```

In the `RunIsolatedTest` method you can add the load testing and what ever you want. This will ensure the test for each client are run on the same thread (which won't give you accuracy in terms of what other operations that thread is taking part in, but it will be better than spinning off multiple threads!). You can then look at CPU-ticks or other processor stats as required.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. My initial thought was that a serial test would not be accurate in reproducing the server crash. The real-world load would be at a shift start hundreds of users will try to log-in within a couple of minutes. Multiple threads would emulate getting requests at the same time. The server then queues the requests and handles them one by one.

Comment: Oh, I see. I did not realize that you were replicating server conditions. Okay, well in that case, just remove the `BackgroundWorker` and fire off the threads using the TPL like you have in the event handler. See http://www.albahari.com/threading/ for a great tutorial...

Comment: Thanks again. I tried looping through it and starting a new task as above. The problem is that I think that the responses gets cut off if I do multiple clients. I've tried using one client and the responses are fine. Any suggestions? I've also tried adding a Wait() to it, wont it negate the whole parallelism since it has to wait for the previous one to finish before it can start?